# How to negate f:if condition in TYPO3 6.2?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I have a TYPO3 6.2 instance ... yes I know it's obsolete, I work parallel on a migration ;)

I have this *if* statement

```
<f:if condition="{v:var.get(name: 'access', useRawKeys: 1)}">
```

Is there a way to negate this statement in TYPO3 6.2.31?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean, if there is no access on the url? Make an <f:else> inside.

Comment: Yes I have the else already. Can I just remove the not used `<f:then`?

Comment: a `<f:then>` is not mandatory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Condition evaluation is very basic in TYPO3 6 and 7: there is no `not`.
Also there is no build in `not`-Viewhelper, you might write it yourself.

But you could easily use the `<f:else>` viewhelper, a `<f:then>` is not necessary:

```
<f:if condition="{v:var.get(name: 'access', useRawKeys: 1)}">
  <f:else>
     : do anything if condition is false
  </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: can I just remove the not necessary `<f:then` ?

Comment: It should be mentioned that this only affects TYPO3 6.2 and v7. With v8 you get the revamped standalone Fluid which supports condition negation and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, if there is no "access" parameter?

```
<f:if condition="{v:var.get(name: 'access', useRawKeys: 1)}">
   <f:else>
       ###your code if there is no access in the URL##
   </f:else>
</f:if>
```